# Why my codeigniter project not working on ubuntu?

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu

My project hosted on linux server works perfect, but in ubuntu its not working, why??

home page is working.....if i click any link showing ----Not found page

Comment: You must post more details about what's going on

Answer (score 2):

Your question contains no information to help troubleshooting.

Usually the way to go when error occurs after moving a web application between environments is to look for differences in configurations, such as the `php.ini` and `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

Calling `php_info();` from both your working and non-working environment and comparing the differences should be a good way to get you started on your troubleshooting.

Don't forget to take a look at your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: my httpd.conf. file is showing empty

Comment: Sorry, the file is located at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: My guess would be missing modules.

Answer (score 0):

Check your 
application/config/config.php file's

$config['uri_protocol']

check if it's set in as AUTO, 
try selecting other protocols such as PATH_INFO, QUERY_STRING, REQUEST_URI, ORIG_PATH_INFO, APP_PATH etc.

one of the protocol should work for you, if not then use this code to check

```
<?php
  print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

which $_SEREVER[???] value has server path information and try using that value in $config['uri_protocol'].

Also check your router file's configuration and .htaccess.
My guess is some trial and error with uri_protocol setting should work for you, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not a case that the .htaccess file is missing in the root CI directory?

Answer (score -1):

You might have a problem with you Apache/PHP configuration.

Comment: I donno where to change bro ....do u have any idea??